# Import products with store-view attribute scope

Tags: magento-1.7, import, csv

Is it possible to use the standard Import functionality (not Dataflow Profiles) to update product information on the store-view level without having to include all other store-views in the import?

For example, if I import the following CSV:

```
sku,_store,description
12345,storeA,Test description
```

It will overwrite the description field for both the `default` and `storeA` store views. In this case I only want to update the `storeA` store view attributes.

Answer (score 4):

The `_store` column should contain the **store code**, not the store name. A store code doesn't have uppercase letters in it, so probably that's the fault. It should work as you wrote if you provide the correct store code.

Comment: I had an issue that I wanted to ensure that the default changed, so I used _store of 0.